# How to target specific values

Tags: css

I am working on a website where centered text sometimes was applied using inline style and others, an external style sheet.

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Centered Text</p>
<p class="center">Centered Text</p>
```

`.center {text-align: center;}`

Is there a CSS selector that can target all centered text regardless of the method by which they were centered?

And please, keep in mind that the question is not whether this method for centering was done properly.

Comment: what you want to do not understand explain more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select it with the following line:

`.center, p[style="text-align: center;"] {
 color:red;
}`

But it's very ugly to use

Comment: It will be better if you use `p[style*="text-align:center"]`. That way it will match all paragraphs that **contain** `text-align:center`.

Comment: ugly, yes (as the the html code it's trying to target), but it works. Thank. ~ But what happen if there are hundreds of class names with `{text-align: center;}`. Is there a way to target those without knowing their class names?

Comment: You can reset it by `* {text-align: left}` but it resets all so you have to set it again after it

Answer (score 0):

why not just define them all as a class and add as needed.
In the css you can define

```
.myCenteringClass {
  text-align: center;
}
```

then anywhere in the html just do

```
<div class="myCenteringClass">asdfadsf</div>
<p class="myCenteringClass">dasfdsaf</p>
```